# Using a stack to validate HTML script

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

I'm attempting to create a program that uses a stack to check whether or not an HTML file has the correct number of closing tags and end tags.

The stack class I'm using is pretty basic:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

The code I've created for the HTML checker so far is:

```
def htmlChecker(html):
    htmlStack = Stack()

    htmlOpen = ['<html>','<head>','<title>','<body>',\
                '<p>','<b>','<u>','<div>','<span>']

    htmlClose = ['</html>','</head>','</title>','</body>',\
                 '</p>','</b>','</u>','</div>','</span>']

    htmlList = html.split()

    for opener in htmlList:
        if opener in htmlOpen:
            htmlStack.push(opener)
        for closer in htmlClose:
            if htmlStack.pop() == closer.replace('/',''):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I understand having the openers and closers in two lists probably isn't efficient, but I'm going very basic with the code to get a feel for the problem.

If I plug in `'<html> <head> </head> <body> </body> </html>'` I should get a return of `True` which I do, but when I input `'<html> <head> </head> <body> </body>'` I still get a return of `True` when I should get `False`.
I've played around a lot with the for loops and the indentation and I still can't figure out why it won't return `False` for incorrect scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the early exit, you could do better than a nested `for` loop by simply checking the inbound value that is in `htmlClose` with the one `pop`ed from the top of the stack:

```
if len(htmlList) % 2: 
    return False
for v in htmlList:
    if v in htmlOpen:
        htmlStack.push(v)
    else:
        if htmlStack.isEmpty(): 
            return False
        else:
            v2 = htmlStack.pop()
            if v.replace('/', '') != v2:
                return False
return True
```

If the stack `isEmpty` when a close tag appears, there wasn't an opening one (you could trim the code down and immediately do `pop` there with a `try-except` to catch the exceptional case and return). If the value popped from the end doesn't match the closing tag, you don't have balance.

Comment: Your solution returns `True` if there are more openers than closers

Comment: Could you give me the sample input you used? @Jason

Comment: `'<html> </html>'`

Comment: That has the same number of openers as closers, why wouldn't it be `True`? @Jason

Comment: My bad I misinterpreted the question. I thought were asking for sample input in general. If I type in `'<html>'` it returns `True`

Comment: @Jason ah, edge-case! Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You **terminate the function** immediately after the **first** closing tag:

```
for opener in htmlList:
    if opener in htmlOpen:
        htmlStack.push(opener)
    for closer in htmlClose:
        if htmlStack.pop() == closer.replace('/',''):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Regardless whether the last `if` condition is `True` or `False`, you **return** and thus and the program. You should **only `return False`**. If the condition does hold, you should keep going until either **one of the next tokens fails, or you reach the end** in which case you should return `True`. So:

```
for opener in htmlList:
    if opener in htmlOpen:
        htmlStack.push(opener)
    for closer in htmlClose:
        if htmlStack.isEmpty() or htmlStack.pop() != closer.replace('/',''):
            return False
return True
```

Note that you do not have to compile a list of HTML tags per se, you could use a regex to make life easier. But that is probably worth another question.

Comment: Your solution gives back `IndexError: pop from an empty list`. Is that my end or your end?